# Firebase Java Query.equalTo() does not work

Tags: java, firebase

I am trying to understand how this method works. I have everything set up and I pushed some strings to the root of my firebase. I made reference to my firebase and I am then trying to make a Query object this way

```
Query refQ = ref.orderByValue().equalTo(word);
```

where word is the same string I pushed to the firebase.

I simply want to print that value to the console.
The weird thing that happens is that the console hangs up like it is in an infinite loop and I need to force it to terminate. I put a print statement after the above line of code and it never gets reached.

So my question is, what am I doing wrong?

Edit: I forgot to mention `word` is static and one of the words I pushed to the firebase. I am doing this to test the functionality.

Comment: If the above is all the code, then indeed nothing will be printed. Firebase doesn't retrieve data until you attach an event listener. See: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

Comment: My problem isn't retrieving the data. My problem is that the console hangs on that line of code. No other code after it is executed. But if I remove the equalTo method call, it runs fine. But I want that constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this minimal sample and just ran it in JDK 1.8.0_31:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/29553461");

    /*
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("puf", "Frank van Puffelen");
    map.put("frank", "Frank van Puffelen");
    map.put("david", "David East");
    map.put("east", "David East");
    ref.setValue(map);
    */

    Query refQ = ref.orderByValue().equalTo("Frank van Puffelen");
    refQ.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            System.out.println("Child added: "+dataSnapshot.getKey()+": "+dataSnapshot.getValue());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
    });

    Console console = System.console();
    if (console != null) {
        console.format("Press ENTER to process.\n");
        console.readLine();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Sleeping for 5 seconds, in hopes that everything is done by then.");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

It prints out:

```
Child added: frank: Frank van Puffelen
Child added: puf: Frank van Puffelen
```

So it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It seems that I wasnt able to create a query in the root of my firebase for whatever reason. I had to do it from some child node

Comment: Nevermind about using the root.
It seems to not work for me if I dont initially set the value of the map. This is just for mine because I ran your code without making the map. Im probably doing something wrong but Ill keep playing around with it. Thanks for your help